# Docker daemon hanging - missing container state file?

Tags: linux, crash, docker

I'm running Docker 1.12.6 on AWS Linux.

All `docker` commands hang.

The AWS instance crashed this morning (still don't know why). Reboot did not work so I stopped and started the instance. When I view `/var/log/docker` I get:

```
time="2017-01-16T10:46:18.829402768Z" level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 21697" 
time="2017-01-16T10:46:18.833508272Z" level=fatal msg="open /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd/054f92393f757e0418b014ed1fa35673fbce2293de43e42153f4e10ec4910c77/state.json: no such file or directory"
```

The container directory exists, but only contains an empty `init` directory. A random search through the other containers shows the same thing.

I assume that missing file is causing the hang. How do I recover?

**Edit:**

Ended up removing then reinstalling, got the message:

```
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Started Docker service, now it is hanging again.

Answer (score 3):

I solved mine by

1. service docker stop
2. Go to /var/run/docker and delete any directory related to the container id
3. Go to /var/lib/docker and delete any directory related to the container id
4. service docker start

Answer (score 2):

@Moreno 's answer worked for me with a small twist:

- stop the docker daemon ( `sudo service docker stop` )
- Delete the folders in containerd (just in case, we also deleted the folders with the same name directly in libconteinerd (/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd)
- start the docker daemon

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same issue. After spending a fair amount of time on this, I've had to roll back to older AMI's which work until I can find a solution for this. The latest ECS agent (1.13.1) was released a couple of days ago - I'm wondering if this could be our issue.

Overview:

- `Docker 1.12.6`
- `ECS Agent 1.13.1`

Upon boot of instance, all `docker` commands hang. Checking `/var/log/docker` shows:

```
level=info msg="libcontainerd: new containerd process, pid: 21687" 
level=fatal msg="open /var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd/{{CONTAINER_HASH}}/state.json: no such file or directory"
```

Same issue where `libcontainerd` contains an empty `init` directory (no `state.json` to be seen!)

Answer (score -1):

Run into the same issue. The instance crashed (unknown reason).
Docker and ECS agent. Reinstalling docker did not help.

What worked for us:

- Kill docker manually (kill pid)
- Delete the folders in containerd (just in case, we also deleted the folders with the same name directly in libconteinerd (/var/run/docker/libcontainerd/containerd)
- Restart docker
- Start ecs

Seen here:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/30984

System up and running again.